# string replace but only if not contained within 2 other strings

Tags: c#, string, replace

Imagine I have a `string` like:

> xxxstrvvv string xxxstringvvv str I am string for testing.

I want to find and replace *all instances* of `str` with `xxxstrvvv` that are not already contained in a `xxxvvv`.

so the result would be:

> xxxstrvvv xxxstrvvving xxxstringvvv xxxstrvvv I am xxxstrvvving for testing

Anyone know an easy way to do this?

Edit:  I want to add another situation to clarify.

> xxxabcstrefgvvv

it should NOT replace this because the str is contained in xxxvvv

Comment: Using [Regex](http://regexr.com) inside of [.LINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx) would be your best bet :)

Answer (score 7):

I suggest using *regular expression* with negative *looking ahead* and *behind*:

```
string source = "xxxstrvvv string xxxstringvvv str I am string for testing.";

string result = Regex.Replace(source, @"(?<!xxx)str(?!vvv)", "xxxstrvvv");
```

**Edit:** Same method, but a bit different pattern for the edited question:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(
    source, 
  @"(?<!xxx[a-zA-Z]*)str(?![a-zA-Z]*vvv)", "xxxstrvvv");
```

Outcomes:

1. `source = "xxxstrvvv string xxxstringvvv str I am string for testing."`:

   `xxxstrvvv xxxstrvvving xxxstringvvv xxxstrvvv I am xxxstrvvving for testing.`
2. `source = "xxxabcstrefgvvv"`:

   `xxxabcstrefgvvv`

Comment: You just got there before me :)

Comment: What if I have a case like "xxxcystrbccvvv"? It would match and replace that that but it shouldn't

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko I edited my question to include the additional case that I think your answer would not handle correctly.

Comment: @Alex: Same method, but different pattern; I've edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I agreed with the answer of Dmitry Bychenko about Regular Expressions.
But, if your request is limited to the requirement on your answer we can use this code:

`string val = "xxxstrvvv string xxxstringvvv str I am string for testing.";
    val = val.Replace("xxxstringvvv", "str");
    val = val.Replace("str","xxxstringvvv");`

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with the regex, but if you want to use replaces, this would work, if you don't have "xxxxxxstrvvvvvv" in your initial string and want to keep them that way:

```
string findString = "str";
string addBefore = "xxx";
string addAfter = "xxx";
string myString = "xxxstrvvv string xxxstringvvv str I am string for testing.";

myString = myString.Replace(findString, addBefore+findString+addAfter);
myString = myString.Replace(addBefore+addBefore+findString+addAfter+addAfter, addBefore+findString+addAfter);
```

Yes; it is ugly. I just basically do that in Notepad++ all the time with `ctrl-H`.

Answer (score -1):

I have written a script in Python. I think you would be able to convert it to C#.

```
one_line = 'xxxstrvvv string xxxstringvvv str I am string for testing'
final_str = ""
arry_len = one_line.split(" ")

for ch in arry_len:
    if 'str' in ch:
      if not 'xxxstrvvv' in ch:
        ch = ch.replace("str","xxxstrvvv")
    final_str = final_str + " " + ch

print final_str
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for "strxxxstrvv" as it wouldn't replace that first "str".  Your flaw is assuming that all "str" instances will be separated by spaces.  Also you're appending an extra space to the beginning.

Comment: @juharr is right. There is no guarantee the string has any spaces at all. Thats why this is a difficult problem. I can't just break it into an array by a reliable separator.

Comment: Well i tried with the above string and the output is: "xxxstrvvvxxxxxxstrvvvvv", which i think is correct